# Unable to upgrade CrystalReports reports to VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am working on a windows application that was developed in VS 2003 and which uses 100's of reports developed in the bundled version of Crystal Reports.

I've been asked to upgrade the system to Visual Studio 2008.  The application code upgrades and runs with out problem but I am unable to run ANY of the crystal reports.

They all fail with

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException = {"Load report     failed."}
ErrorID = LoadingReportFailed {4096}
Message = "Load report failed."
Source = "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine"
StackTrace = "   at .F(String   , EngineExceptionErrorID  )    
at .B(String , Int32 )    
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String reportName,     OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)    
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine....
```

I have been unable to find a reason why this would be.  As far as I am aware Crystal Reports 10.5.3700.0 that is bundled in VS 2008 should run reports created in Crystal Reports 9.1.5000.0 that is bundled in VS 2003.

I have checked all the usual stuff, the file exists, permissions are good and the reports work in the version of the app compiled in VS 2003 so there is nothing wrong with the reports themselves.

The two applications are using the same database were all of the application settings are stored.  I have not made any modifications to the code and the VS 2008 app works otherwise perfectly.

I have tried to open the original reports (unmodified) and also I've upgraded a few of them in VS 2008. Neither work.

I have also tried to create a reference to Crystal.Reports.Engine 9.1.5000.0 but VS wont allow this.

Any help would be much appreciated.  There a several hundred reports and most of them are very complicated.  Manually recreating this number of reports is not feasible.

Hopefully there is a solution to this.

Thanks in advance.